mypy with pydantic field_validator
With pydantic, is there a way for mypy to be hinted so it doesn't raise an error in this scenario, where there's a field_validator modifying the type?
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    x: int

    @field_validator("x", mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def to_int(cls, v: str) -> int:
        return len(v)


MyModel(x='test')


why not providing type hints as x: int | str?

because it's not an int | str, it's an int and there's a field validator to convert it to int.  This is from the docs: https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/7262#issuecomment-1695603472

imagine you have a Pydantic struct that can take an int | str, but the field value is ALWAYS an int because the field_validator will always ensure it's converted to an int.  If I say int | str, now I need to validate this every time something uses the field, or I need to create a method to convert it when it's accessed.

If you're always inserting a string there, it might be better to use a computed_field. Something along this, maybe?
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    input: str

    @computed_field
    def x(self) -> int:
        return len(self.input)

I think it's very counterintuitive if you see the model with the int declaration while it would raise type errors if you put an integer inside a JSON at that place.

yeah i see, i just wanted to not store the value and the computed value, since once the computed value is calculated the input value can safely be dropped

@Rob If you really really want to drop the value, I'd suggest using 2 different schemas. Using just the length of the string and not the string itself is a logical reduction. If you simply drop the original value you would be unable to do a full roundtrip with the model since you're losing information with dropping the original string. That's in best scenario ugly af and in worst scenario very likely to produce bugs especially when interacting with APIs :)

that's great advice, i think i understand your perspective.  so a BaseModel should always preserve its initialization arguments?

@Rob I'd say, in some circustances stuff like data cleansing is ok. I used that on data migration projects. But most of the time, especially in big and complex code bases, it's best to only do validation on the models and no implicit mutation of data.

I'm still not convinced that it's a necessary approach, but here's a really simple option how to achieve this:
from pydantic import BaseModel


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    x: int

    def __init__(self, x: int | str):
        super().__init__(x=len(x) if isinstance(x, str) else x)

MyModel(x='test')


It's not necessary, just syntactically cleaner if I can accept a type different from the desired validated type in the init
